# How are threads and processes implemented in Windows CE?

Tags: multithreading, multiprocessing, windows-ce

I read that Threads are the primary unit of execution on Windows CE. What does this mean exactly? How are threads implemented and how are processes implemented?

Comment: Did you try reading the source? At least parts of it are available. Also, read [ask], in particular think about what an answer to your questions should provide to be accepted. Further, if you want to clarify what someone meant, ask them. At the very least, if you quote someone, give according reference!

Answer (score 0):

In ce a process defines a isolated address space and lives as long as its main thread is running. Typically the main thread is the main() entry point in a classical C program and the process is terminated as soon as you return from that function (ok, there are some initialization and destruction steps...but let's keep this simple). When the main thread terminates all the memory and resources allocated by all the threads of the process are released.
Threads are the execution units. You need to have at least the main thread, but you can create additional ones. Those are terminated when the main thread terminates.
The only difference between main thread and all the other threads is that main determines the "lifetime" of your process.
The scheduler cares about threads. When a thread time quantum terminates or an high-priority thread needs to run, it schedules the new thread and if it belongs to a different process than the one running, it re-configures the virtual memory address space to match.
If a process has one thread and another one has 99 and all of them have the same priority and all of them keep the CPU busy for the whole quantum process one will use 1% of the CPU and process 2 99%. 
Of course, being and hard realtime OS, CE has also priority management, but this, again, applies to threads and not processes.